# TypeError: msecs must be a number in the running app

Tags: node.js, newrelic

Yesterday, Eventually I have encountered with the strange issue with all of my API servers during peak hours. There was below mentioned intermittent error. I am using several third party services with the application. Some of the services used with the apps are newrelic, airbrake, pusher etc.

Stack:

```
Node v0.12.2
pm2 2.4.5
request module: 2.81.0
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: msecs must be a number
at Object.exports.enroll (timers.js:156:11) 
at Socket.setTimeout (net.js:329:12) 
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (_http_client.js:558:10) 
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:199:16) 
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:129:20) 
at tickOnSocket (_http_client.js:486:7) at _http_client.js:497:7 at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Errors in airbrake:
Error: msecs must be a number
timers.js:156 in Object.exports.enroll
net.js:337 in Socket.setTimeout
_http_client.js:565
events.js:199 in ClientRequest.g
events.js:129 in ClientRequest.emit
_http_client.js:493 in tickOnSocket
_http_client.js:504
node.js:381 in process._tickDomainCallback
```

Things I have tried already but nothing helped. The errors were coming continuously for 12-15 hours.

1. Updating node version to 6.9.1
2. Downgrading request module version till 2.2.1
3. Tried Adding below request timeout where I have used request config.

   var request = require('request') 
   request = request.defaults({timeout: 120000})
4. Tried running the app.js with the node.
5. Tried adding a timeout in .bowerrc.
6. Deployed new server and with code again on it, but the error was still there.

The error was not reoccurred from past 3 hours. I am not able to find the RCA and also not sure if it reoccurs in peak hours.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated all dependencies to the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I have tried updating Node to 6.9.1, Require to 2.81.0, Pm2 to 2.4.5 version and also tried running the application with node instead of pm2 but nothing helped. As of now, I am not able to see the error while running pm2 logs. I am even not sure if the issue was with some third party application which I am using with the app. I am just anticipating the situation here, but not able to get the exact issue.

Comment: The _"Errors in airbrake"_ seems to suggest that the error is happening there. It also depends on `request`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me the indication of the first error?. Also, I was getting the same error with newrelic so I removed it and It solved the error which was coming with it.

Comment: I don't know where that error is coming from, the message seems to come from your own code, so that might make it easier to narrow down. Are you setting a specific timeout when creating the Airbrake client?

Comment: No, I have not set timeout while creating the AirBrake client.